# Boundary crossing rate by independent Monte Carlo samples

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations

I have written a Monte Carlo simulation, where I have a Brownian particle in a certain potential energy landscape. The particle moves in a squared 2d space (Simulation space) with periodic boundary conditions. In the middle of my simulation space, there is a circle which I call the event boundary. I want to know the average rate at which my particle crosses the boundary. Let's say that every Monte Carlo step, I sample a position of my particle, based on the potential energy landscape. I thus samples positions both within and outside the event boundary. Can I deduce what the rate is for crossing the boundary based on this alone? The tricky thing here is thus that when I sample a position within the event boundary, this corresponds to a particle trajectory that has crossed already further than just the boundary.

I am not looking for a different simulation procedure where I track particle trajectories instead, I want to know fundamentally if there is a solution to my problem. Can you know the average rate for crossing the boundary solely based on independent samples of the position of the particle?

Thank you for your future answer!

[image]